# What does mg/s mean when running geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I'm running geth for the first time with:

`geth --testnet`

I can see it downloading the blockchain and it's showing progress with logs like

`core/blockchain.go:1047] imported 311 blocks,  2940 txs (646.960 Mg│total 16
) in    6.924s (93.431 Mg/s). #76545 [f42c1bd1… / d1e25194…]`

What is mg here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **M**illion **g**as / **s**econd.

This is what your node is able to process. It's a way to measure your nodes performance and it's more comparable than blocks per second or transactions per second.

- You importet 311 blocks.
- Containing 2940 transactions.
- Which paid 646.960 Million gas to cover fees.
- In 6.924 seconds.

That is:

```
646.96/6.924
= 93.4373194685153090699
```

> Mg/s